# Formatting NumberPicker

Tags: android, layout

My default NumberPicker looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look more like this:

[image]

I'm not married to the +/- thing, but I want a smaller widget that can fit on a screen along with other stuff. My understanding is that setting the theme in the Manifest to one based on Theme will do the trick, but no joy. Here is my Manifest entry:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light" >
```

I am using Android 4.3 platform and API 18 on my ADV.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: that styling looks like the Gingerbread widget, if you really wanted it you could set target-api=10 ?

Comment: I don't necessarily need the +/-, but I want a smaller widget.